# android set hidden the keyboard on press enter (in a EditText)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When my user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the virtual android "user validate entry!" keyboard my keyboard stay visible! (Why?)

Here my Java code...

```
private void initTextField() {
    entryUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentEntrySalary);
    entryUser.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        userValidateEntry();
                        return true;
                }
            }

          return true;
        }
    });
}

private void userValidateEntry() {
    System.out.println("user validate entry!");
}
```

... here my View

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/studentEntrySalary" android:text="Foo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Maybe something wrong on my virtual device?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This should do it:

```
yourEditTextHere.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                // NOTE: In the author's example, he uses an identifier
                // called searchBar. If setting this code on your EditText
                // then use v.getWindowToken() as a reference to your 
                // EditText is passed into this callback as a TextView

                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBar
                        .getApplicationWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
               userValidateEntry();
               // Must return true here to consume event
               return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your a genus ! Thanks
(Change searchBar buy yourEditTextHere)

Comment: 1. The code seems not working when I change the code to
   if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D))
   So after pressing D the soft input form does not hide.

Comment: For anyone else that sees Samir's comment, it's because this code sets the `OnEditorActionListener`, which is only called when a key like Enter is pressed, and not regular character keys.

Comment: And if I really need to hide the keyboard on a "regular" character press? Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

Keep the singleLine="true" and add imeOptions="actionDone" to the EditText.
Then in the OnEditorActionListener check if actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE, like so (but change it to your implementation):

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                if ((username.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                        && (password.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(username.getWindowToken(),
                            0);
                    doLogin();
                }
            }
```

Comment: In my case, `imeOptions="actionDone"` was enough, no code was needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you make the text box a single line (I believe the propery is called SingleLine in the layout xml files) it will exit out of the keyboard on enter.

Here you go: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_singleLine

Comment: negative. It's still the same problem with android:singleLine="true"

Comment: This works for me with an Android 4 (Tablet 4.0.3, build target 4.2) in case it is Android version dependent (I have not tried it on other versions).

Answer (score 2):

just add this line in your edit text.

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"'
```

you can specify the next edit text id to move to that edit text on click of the keyboard done button.

Answer (score 1):

I am create a custom component who extends AutoCompleteTextView, like in the example below:

```
public class PortugueseCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
...
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event != null &&  (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager =
                (InputMethodManager) getContext().
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                this.getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

I am using this code in the AlertDialog.Builder, but is possible to be using to Activity.